# Mocha istanbul coverage xml file generation

Tags: xml, jenkins, mocha.js, cobertura

I'am trying to generate an xml file that contains informations about unit test coverage that i made with mocha ( Backend unit tests in Angularjs ).

I executed my front end unit tests with jasminejs and i can integrate the frontend coverage with cobertura plugin in jenkins.

My question is how can i do the same as in front end , but in backend this time ( with mocha ) ? 
I mean generate Mocha unit test coverage file and view it using Cobertura plugin in jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [link](http://www.mikkolehtinen.com/blog/2013-01-31-jenkins-setup-for-a-javascript-project/)

That refers to... https://www.npmjs.org/package/istanbul.

On first link, you can change `ISTANBUL_REPORTERS=html,text-summary,cobertura` to `ISTANBUL_REPORTERS=cobertura`

At the end, a file cobertura-coverage.xml will be generated. Publish this file in your jenkins with the Cobertura plugin.